# Removing stubborn modules

Tags: linux, kernel, package-management

I'm trying to programatically stomp on bluetooth on RHEL5.

I've got the service stopped -- no problem.  Also no problem on `rpm -e` for the associated bluetooth packages, bluez-*.

```
ps -aef | grep -v grep | egrep -c '(sdpd|hcid)'
```

returns zero , so I know the daemons are gone.

For some reason, I just can't get the modules to unload.  `modprobe -rv` keeps saying they're in use.

Dependencies look like this:

```
bluetooth -> bnep
          -> l2cap 
                 -> rfcomm
                 -> hidp
          -> rfcomm
          -> hidp
```

But, even starting at the top so that dependencies are simple, `modprobe -rv bluetooth` returns **FATAL: Module bluetooth is in use**.

So, how do I find out what processes are using this module?  It doesn't seem to be in /proc/modules, or lsof.

Command `lsof` still shows something hooked.

```
# lsmod | egrep '(bnep|hidp|rfcomm|l2cap|bluetooth)'
bnep                   82241  0 
hidp                   83521  0 
rfcomm                104809  0 
l2cap                  89281  5 bnep,hidp,rfcomm
bluetooth             118597  4 bnep,hidp,rfcomm,l2cap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do an `lsmod`, what is the reference count for the bluetooth module?  Also,

```
lsmod | grep "bluetooth"
```

just to make sure there aren't other dependencies that may have been missed.

---

Eject modules in the following order:

```
rmmod bnep
rmmod hidp
rmmod rfcomm
rmmod l2cap
```

Then try

```
rmmod bluetooth
lsmod
```

Comment: Something's got it hooked, but I have no idea how to know *what*.  That's not very Unix-y.  I don't know the answer, but I do expect the system to expose it somewhere.

# lsmod | egrep '(bnep|hidp|rfcomm|l2cap|bluetooth)'
bnep                   82241  0 
hidp                   83521  0 
rfcomm                104809  0 
l2cap                  89281  5 bnep,hidp,rfcomm
bluetooth             118597  4 bnep,hidp,rfcomm,l2cap

Comment: Huh?  That worked.  I had been using "modprobe -r" instead of "lmmod", per the lmmod man page.  It says, "Most users will want to use mod-probe(8) instead, with the -r option."

I don't know why one worked and the other didn't.  Thank you for taking the time to help me out...

Comment: rmmod was always meant to remove a module.  modprobe's original function was to attempt to determine if a module was needed, and then load it if so (from the 2.0 days)

Comment: anyways, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

What about disabling the module in /etc/modprobe.conf or blacking listing under /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist and then just rebooting?

Does something map to a /dev device and you could use lsof on that?

I think you have already tried the normal options...